# Clang: functions aligning

Tags: assembly, attributes, clang, size, memory-alignment

I have generated a lot of small functions. But because the default alignment in Clang is 16 bytes, the size of the resulting file is too large. How to change alignment to 4 bytes?

```
invoke_register_none_:
0041B750 FFE2             jmp edx
0041B752 662E0F1F840000000000 db $66 $2e $0f $1f $84 $00 $00 $00 $00 $00 
0041B75C 0F1F4000         db $0f $1f $40 $00 
invoke_register_none_g:
0041B760 8B01             mov eax,[ecx]
0041B762 FFE2             jmp edx
0041B764 662E0F1F840000000000 db $66 $2e $0f $1f $84 $00 $00 $00 $00 $00 
0041B76E 6690             nop 
invoke_register_none_gg:
0041B770 8B01             mov eax,[ecx]
0041B772 8B4904           mov ecx,[ecx+$04]
0041B775 87D1             xchg ecx,edx
0041B777 FFE1             jmp ecx
0041B779 0F1F8000000000   db $0f $1f $80 $00 $00 $00 $00
```

Comment: gcc has `-falign-functions=4` which clang also accepts but seems to ignore.

Comment: No, [it's in bytes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-falign-functions). Yay for consistency.

Comment: @Jester: Oh, nvm then.  That rules out my 2^4 guess of why you didn't see any effect.

Comment: @Jester, this flag does not work in Clang

Comment: The set of flags "-mllvm -align-all-functions=2" helped make 4 bytes alignment!